# Java StringTokenizer Different Data Types

Tags: java

I've recently had a small class test in college for java and I need help.

I have an object called "Products" that takes (String, double, int) as it's parameters.

I've created an ArrayList

```
ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
```

What I'm trying to do is use a StringTokenizer to read from this format and
store it into individual objects and then I want to print out the object contents.

```
PR0001 7.99 10
PR0002 29.99 0
PR0003 5.99 25
PR0004 99.99 50
PR0005 17.99 15
PR0006 15.99 0
PR0007 19.99 35
PR0008 39.99 40
PR0009 2.99 0
PR0010 3.99 5
```

My main method is:

```
package objects;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
public class main_object_class
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
        String fileName = "products.txt";

        try
        {
        Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        while(file.hasNextLine())
        {
            StringTokenizer strToken = new StringTokenizer(file.next(), " ");
            while(strToken.hasMoreTokens())
            {
                String pCode = strToken.nextToken();
                System.out.println("pCode Works");
                double pPrice = Double.parseDouble(strToken.nextToken());
                System.out.println("pPrice Works");
                int pQuantity = Integer.parseInt(strToken.nextToken());
                System.out.println("pQuantity Works");
                products.add(new Product(pCode,pPrice,pQuantity));
                System.out.println("Storing Works");
            }
        }

        for(int i=0;i<products.size();i++)
        {
            System.out.println(products);
        }

        }catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My Product method:

```
package objects;
public class Product
{
    private String pCode = "";
    private double pPrice = 0;
    private int pQuantity = 0;

    public Product(String c, double p, int q)
    {
        pCode = c;
        pPrice = p;
        pQuantity = q;
    }

    public void setCode(String c)
    {
        pCode = c;
    }

    public String getCode()
    {
        return pCode;
    }

    public void setPrice(double p)
    {
        pPrice = p;
    }

    public double getPrice()
    {
        return pPrice;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int q)
    {
        pQuantity = q;
    }

    public int getQuantity()
    {
        return pQuantity;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Code : " + getCode() + "\tPrice : $" + getPrice() + "\tQuantity : " + getQuantity();
    }


}
```

My Error:

```
run:
pCode Works
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:349)
    at objects.main_object_class.main(main_object_class.java:24)
C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I'd really like to thank for all the input. I've tried all solutions and they all worked. Yet I'm going to go with @Jerin Joseph solution!

Comment: You call `nextToken()` 3 times after checking just once if there are more tokes left in `strToken`. (Propably some problems there...)

Comment: How do I check all of them for different data types then? 
What I'm trying to do is pass 3 different data types using a tokenizer into an object.

Comment: Read the documentation to figure out why a `NoSuchElementException` is thrown. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

Comment: Basically its not the type of data you want to retrieve (since it will always be a String). But the amount of Tokens...

Comment: *FYI:* Read the javadoc of [`StringTokenizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html), which has been saying the following since at least Java 5: *`StringTokenizer` is a **legacy class** that is retained for compatibility reasons although **its use is discouraged in new code**. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the `split` method of `String` or the java.util.regex package instead.*

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for letting me know that! It's just we're following a model in college. But they don't discourage us from using
>Split method on  a 
>String.

P.S: I'm terrible at formatting :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Read the file line by line, `Scanner::nextLine()` gives you one line at a time.

   `StringTokenizer strToken = new StringTokenizer(file.nextLine(), " ");`
2. Remove the `while(strToken.hasMoreTokens())`,  You need to check it for every token you parse.

Change it to ,

```
String pCode = "";
double pPrice = 0;
int pQuantity = 0;

if(strToken.hasMoreTokens()){
    pCode = strToken.nextToken();
    System.out.println("pCode Works");
}
if(strToken.hasMoreTokens()){
    pPrice = Double.parseDouble(strToken.nextToken());
    System.out.println("pPrice Works");
}
if(strToken.hasMoreTokens()){
    pQuantity = Integer.parseInt(strToken.nextToken());
    System.out.println("pQuantity Works");
}
products.add(new Product(pCode,pPrice,pQuantity));
System.out.println("Storing Works");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you check if there are Tokens left, and than call "nextToken()" 3 times. Where there cannot be a guranty that there will be 3 tokens left, unless you specifically check for it. Like so:

```
 if(strToken.countTokens() >= 3)
 {
     \\ here you can call strToken.nextToken() safly for 3 times.
 }
```

Your current approuch is a classic approuch for basic itteration. E.g.

```
 while(strToken.hasMoreElements())
  {
      String next = strToken.nextToken();
  }
```

But it allows only one safe call of "nextToken()" between the bracets.

I hope this helped